# Replacing all non numeric characters with a single character

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I need to be able to turn a string like this: 98$#221$$99

Into this: 98-221-99

The code I'm using below replaces all non-numeric characters, but it replaces them individually. I need it to only replace it with one hyphen.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$number = '82#$991';
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", " ", $number);
$number = str_replace(" ", "-", $number);
```

The output of this is: 82--991

I need it to be: 82-991

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of calling `str_replace()` after `preg_replace()`, you can use a [**quantifier**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html).  The `+` quantifier tells the regex engine to match the preceding token "one or more" times.

```
$number = '98$#221$$99';
$number = preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '-', $number);
echo $number; //=> "98-221-99"
```